# how to version control a site with Bazaar?

Tags: ftp, webserver, bazaar

basically, I want to make a local branch of my website so that I can edit files then merge them back to the server

this is what I did:

```
root@aziz-HP:~# bzr init ftp://user@example.com/public_html/forums
FTP user@example.com password:
Created a standalone branch (format: 2a)                                                                                                    
root@aziz-HP:~# cd /var/www/
root@aziz-HP:/var/www# bzr checkout ftp://user@example.com/public_html/forums
FTP user@example.com password:
root@aziz-HP:/var/www#
```

but the local folder is still empty except for ".bzr" directory

Comment: Just one note: DO NOT USE ROOT!

Answer (score 1):

You're creating a branch in ftp://user@example.com/public_html/forums. Since this branch is new and nothing has been added to it, it will be empty when you check it out later.

See the bzr documentation for instructions on how to add files to a branch.